# List files with MATLAB which are not .m files

Tags: regex, matlab, regex-negation, dir

I can list all .m files in the current directory with this code: `dir(fullfile('.', '*.m'))`.

But how to change the regular expression  that only files will be listed which have **not** the ending .m (files without "ending" should be included as well)?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
fls = dir( fullfile('.','*') );
sel = arrayfun( @(x) ~x.isdir && ~strcmp(x.name(end-1:end),'.m'), fls );
fls = fls(sel);
```